# Prevent requests to 127.0.0.1 from being forwarded to http_proxy

Tags: networking, proxy, http-proxy

I have this on my machine:

```
$ cat /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh 
export http_proxy=http://192.168.1.30:3128
export https_proxy=https://192.168.1.30:3128
```

That works great, until I need to use an HTTP interface with an application on the localhost.

```
$ wget localhost
--2023-03-02 06:54:52--  http://localhost/
Connecting to 192.168.1.30:3128... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
2023-03-02 06:54:52 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.

$ wget 127.0.0.1
--2023-03-02 06:55:20--  http://127.0.0.1/
Connecting to 192.168.1.30:3128... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2023-03-02 06:55:20 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Is there a way to prevent `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` requests from being forwarded to the proxy?

---

Details:

This machine isn't connected directly to the internet.  It has no gateway or default route.  But it is on a LAN with a proxy machine (192.168.1.30) that has a proxy server installed (port 3128) and has an internet connection.

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: ...
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
2: eno1: ...
    altname enp24s0f0
    inet 192.168.1.100/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eno1

$ ip route
192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.100

$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost

$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `wget` man page:

> **ENVIRONMENT**
>
> Wget supports proxies for both HTTP and FTP retrievals.  The standard way to specify proxy location, which Wget recognizes, is using the following environment variables:
>
> **http_proxy** and **https_proxy**
>
> If set, the http_proxy and https_proxy variables should contain the URLs of the proxies for HTTP and HTTPS connections respectively.
>
> **ftp_proxy**
>
> This variable should contain the URL of the proxy for FTP connections.  It is quite common that http_proxy and ftp_proxy are set to the same URL.
>
> **no_proxy**
>
> This variable should contain a comma-separated list of domain extensions proxy should *not* be used for. For instance, if the value of no_proxy is `.mit.edu`, proxy will not be used to retrieve documents from MIT.

So, you should change your `/etc/profile.d/proxy.sh` to:

```
export http_proxy=http://192.168.1.30:3128
export https_proxy=https://192.168.1.30:3128
export no_proxy="127.0.0.1,localhost"
```

If you have a GUI web browser that does not use the `*_proxy` environment variables, then you could create a [proxy autoconfiguration file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config), name the file `proxy.pac`, have your local HTTP server provide it with MIME type `application/x-ns-proxy-autoconfig`.

Then configure your desktop environment and/or web browser(s) to use that autoconfiguration file, by specifying a proxy autoconfiguration URL like `http://localhost/some/where/proxy.pac` (or maybe even `file:///some/location/proxy.pac`) in the proxy settings of the desktop environment or web browser.

In your case, the contents of the file could be:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
    // If not a http: or https: URL, go direct always.
    if (!shExpMatch(url,"http*") {
        return "DIRECT";
    }

    // If the destination is:
    // - any 127.*.*.* address
    // - or anything like "localhost*"
    // - or the web browser host's own IP address
    // Then go direct to destination.

    else if (shExpMatch(host, "127.*")
        || shExpMatch(host, "localhost*")
        || host == myIpAddress()) {
        return "DIRECT";
    }
    else {
        // Otherwise, use the proxy specified here.
        return "PROXY 192.168.1.30:3128";
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic!  I didn't look into `man wget` because I've reproduced the problem with `curl` and `python3-urllib3`, so I figured it was system-wide and not application-specific.  I didn't realize that these applications just all happen to have code to handle these variables.

Comment: One might say that those environment variables might be the closest thing to an universal standard for configuring a HTTP(S) proxy we have for unix-like operating systems. The various desktop environments can have their own system-wide and per-user proxy settings, but those may not always apply to command-line programs or services executed outside a user's login session.